# How to predict the size of a specific data type in C?

Tags: c, types

I know that size of data types in C aren't fixed for all Architects.

But for a fixed CPU architect,how can I predict the size of `sizeof(unsigned short)` ?

By **predict** I mean not by test(`printf("%d",sizeof(unsigned short));`)

Answer (score 3):

Read your compiler documentation.

Answer (score 1):

you either read the compiler documentation or write a program you can run on the architecture / compiler you want to gather information about:

```
/* $Id: sizeof.c,v 1.1 2009/07/05 10:37:54 sms Exp $
 * www.pccl.demon.co.uk
 * Program to display data sizes. */

#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <time.h>
#include    <sys/types.h>

#define printsize(x)    printf ("sizeof (" #x ")    = %d\n", sizeof (x))

main ()
{
    printf ("\nC\n");
    printsize (char);
    printsize (double);
    printsize (float);
    printsize (int);
    printsize (long);
    printsize (long long);
    printsize (short);
    printsize (void *);

    printf("\n");
    printsize (clock_t);
    printsize (gid_t);
    printsize (pid_t);
    printsize (size_t);
    printsize (ssize_t);
    printsize (time_t);
    printsize (uid_t);
}
```

http://www.pccl.demon.co.uk/C/sizeof.html

Comment: Yep, "Have the build system test it" is a common solution.

Comment: I'd throw in the function pointer size as well. It can differ from the data pointer size.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "predict" the size in bytes, but you can "predict" the range:

```
#include <limits.h>

#if USHRT_MAX < 65535
/* less than the minimum guaranteed by the Standard: will never happen */
#elif USHRT_MAX == 65535
/* minimum guaranteed by the Standard: 2 8-bit bytes */
#elif USHRT_MAX <= 420042
/* a little more room than guaranteed by the Standard */
#elif USHRT_MAX <= 2000000000
/* a lot more room than guaranteed by the Standard */
#else
/* 640K ought to be enough for anybody */
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have consistent, predictable sizes for your data types, you shouldn't be using `short`, `int`, `long`, etc.  The C99 standard introduced standard types to specify exact-width integers.  Include the [stdint.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdint.h#Integer_types) header to get access to types like `uint16_t` and `int64_t` for 16-bit unsigned and 64-bit signed integers, respectively, regardless of what architecture you're running on.

Comment: The fixed-width types will only exist if they make sense in the architecture; otherwise they'll be undefined. If you want true portability, **don't worry about specific sizes, and use C99 minimum width types: `uint_least16_t`, `int_least64_t`, ...**

Comment: @pmg: Does anything in the spec promise whether e.g. the sum of two `uint_least8_t` will be a signed or unsigned quantity?  I would think that unless one the code is liberally sprinkled with explicit casts, using `uint_least8_t` rather than `uint8_t` would likely replace compilation failures on machines that don't support 8-bit bytes with erroneous behavior--not exactly an improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Use uint16_t instead - that is guarranteed by stdint.h to be exactly 16-bits or to prevent compilation if no 16-bit value is possible on the architecture.

If you just want to check, consider using C_ASSERT(sizeof(T) == 2) - this will cause a compile-time error if T is *not* 2 bytes long. That way you can know that T is 2 bytes long in every compiled binary (since if it wasn't for some strange compiler reason, the build would have failed).

Comment: `C_ASSERT()` isn't defined in the C standard. One has to write it for their compiler.